# Cannot generate a Pages controller in the Rails 3 tutorial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am working through the Michael Hartl Rails 3 tutorial, and I am currently on Chapter 3. The tutorial asks me to generate a Pages controller with actions for a Home page and a Contact page using the command line: "$ rails generate controller Pages home contact".

This is the output I get:

```
ruby 1.9.2p290 (2011-07-09) [i386-mingw32]

C:\Users\abcd\rails_projects2\sample_app>rails generate controller Pages home
contact
C:/Users/abcd/rails_projects2/sample_app/config/application.rb:8:in `require':
 no such file to load -- sprockets/railtie (LoadError)
        from C:/Users/abcd/rails_projects2/sample_app/config/application.rb:8:
in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/comman
ds.rb:15:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/comman
ds.rb:15:in `<top (required)>'
        from script/rails:6:in `require'
        from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

**The contents of my config/application.rb file:**

```
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)

# Pick the frameworks you want:
require "active_record/railtie"
require "action_controller/railtie"
require "action_mailer/railtie"
require "active_resource/railtie"
require "sprockets/railtie"
# require "rails/test_unit/railtie"

if defined?(Bundler)
  # If you precompile assets before deploying to production, use this line
  Bundler.require *Rails.groups(:assets => %w(development test))
  # If you want your assets lazily compiled in production, use this line
  # Bundler.require(:default, :assets, Rails.env)
end

module SampleApp
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # Settings in config/environments/* take precedence over those specified here.
    # Application configuration should go into files in config/initializers
    # -- all .rb files in that directory are automatically loaded.

    # Custom directories with classes and modules you want to be autoloadable.
    # config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/extras)

    # Only load the plugins named here, in the order given (default is alphabetical).
    # :all can be used as a placeholder for all plugins not explicitly named.
    # config.plugins = [ :exception_notification, :ssl_requirement, :all ]

    # Activate observers that should always be running.
    # config.active_record.observers = :cacher, :garbage_collector, :forum_observer

    # Set Time.zone default to the specified zone and make Active Record auto-convert to this zone.
    # Run "rake -D time" for a list of tasks for finding time zone names. Default is UTC.
    # config.time_zone = 'Central Time (US & Canada)'

    # The default locale is :en and all translations from config/locales/*.rb,yml are auto loaded.
    # config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('my', 'locales', '*.{rb,yml}').to_s]
    # config.i18n.default_locale = :de

    # Configure the default encoding used in templates for Ruby 1.9.
    config.encoding = "utf-8"

    # Configure sensitive parameters which will be filtered from the log file.
    config.filter_parameters += [:password]

    # Enable the asset pipeline
    config.assets.enabled = true

    # Version of your assets, change this if you want to expire all your assets
    config.assets.version = '1.0'
  end
end
```

I have also discovered that when I try to run the command line "rails server", I get a similar error message. I don't know if this information is useful.

Thank you!

Comment: can you please post the contents of your Gemfile ?

Comment: source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.0.9'
gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.3'

group :development do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.6.1'
end

group :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.6.1'
  gem 'webrat', '0.7.1'
end

Comment: The tutorial had me change the contents of the Gemfile to the above post.

Comment: Please show us the contents of your `config/application.rb` file. It looks like there's something on line 8 that is calling to sprockets/railtie. Please post this as an edit to your question rather than another comment, just so the formatting is neater

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the tutorial is using Rails 3.0.9, but you've created your application using a later version of the Rails gem.

`sprockets` was added in version 3.1. Even though you've updated your Gemfile to specify Rails 3.0.9, the code that was generated when you ran `rails new sample_app` is expecting Rails 3.1 gems to be available (i.e. simply changing the Gemfile isn't enough to change the Rails version of the application).

You could try simply commenting out the reference to `sprockets` in your `application.rb` file, but even if that works for now it's likely there'll be other differences that'll cause errors later.

Your best bet is probably to start from scratch, but make sure you're using Rails 3.0.9. If you're using [RVM](https://rvm.io), you could create a new gemset and install 3.0.9 into it, then use that gemset.

Alternatively, when you create the application specify the version of the gem you want in the command:

```
rails _3.0.9_ new sample_app
```

If you use this second method, then after you've created the application, simply using `rails` by itself to issue commands (like `generate`) should be okay, as Rails does some magic to determine the version of the app and use the right gem version, even if a later version is installed - you don't need to use `rails _3.0.9_` all the time.

Answer (score 0):

in your config/application.rb file, try to uncomment the "sprockets" line like this:

```
# require "sprockets/railtie"
```

Then check if it works afterwards... that should do the trick...

But if not, please check your Gemfile, it should look something like this:

```
# gem "rails", "~> 3.1.0"      # or "3.0.9"
gem "rails" , "3.0.9"
gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.3'         # or whatever DB you use
```

If that still doesn't help, check which version of sprockets you have installed:
in a shell, do a:

```
$ gem list | grep sprock
sprockets (2.0.0.beta.10)
```

Comment: I edited config/application.rb and ran generate command

C:\Users\abcd\rails_projects2\sample_app>rails generate controller Pages home
contact
C:/Users/abcd/rails_projects2/sample_app/config/application.rb:13:in `<top (re
quired)>': undefined method `groups' for Rails:Module (NoMethodError)
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/comman
ds.rb:15:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/comman
ds.rb:15:in `<top (required)>'
        from script/rails:6:in `require'
        from script/rails:6:in `<main>'

Comment: My Gemfile is also correct, and this is my version of sprockets: sprockets (2.0.1, 2.0.0)

Comment: can you please cut+paste your Gemfile below your question?